# What is the significance of 2nd John being addressed to the "elect lady"?

Tags: 2-john

2nd John begins like this:

> The elder to the elect lady and her children, whom I love in truth, and not only I, but also all who know the truth — *2nd John 1, ESV*

Is this a letter to Mary? Or does this address suggest anything about allowing women to be elders in a church?

Comment: "would this also be used for example as to allowing women to be Elders in a church?" I don't see why. It doesn't say the "elect lady" (Ἐκλεκτῇ κυρίᾳ) is an elder (πρεσβύτερος), but rather, the author is. In case you are interested, see p. 181 (in the book). http://www.simply-a-christian.com/texts/Henry_Alford/Greek_Testament_Volume_4.pdf

Comment: [Who is the “elect lady” of Second John?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/5002/3555)

Comment: Is it really constructive to migrate a question just so that it can immediately be marked as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

The author identified *himself* as “the elder”

> "The elder ***unto*** the elect lady and her children, whom I love in the
>   truth; and not I only, but also all they that have known the truth;" [(2 John 1:1)](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/2-jn/1.1?lang=eng#0)

Since the epistle addresses a group of people, many commentators conclude that “the elect lady” actually refers to a Christian congregation, which is evidenced by the last verse of the same chapter:

> "*The children of thy **elect sister*** greet thee. Amen." [(2 John 1:13)](https://www.lds.org/manual/new-testament-student-manual/1-john-2-john-3-john-and-jude/chapter-52-1-john-2-john-3-john-and-jude?lang=eng)

The Greek term for church is feminine, and it was common to personify the Church as a woman (see [Ephesians 5:25–27, 32;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/eph/5.25-27%2C32?lang=eng#24) [Revelation 12:1–4, 17;](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rev/12.1-4%2C17?lang=eng#0) [19:7–8](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/nt/rev/19.7-8?lang=eng#6)). Another possibility is that “the elect lady and her children” were John’s wife and family.

---

<sup>[Chapter 52: 1 John, 2 John, 3 John, and Jude](https://www.lds.org/manual/new-testament-student-manual/1-john-2-john-3-john-and-jude/chapter-52-1-john-2-john-3-john-and-jude?lang=eng). New Testament Student Manual, 2014</sup>

Comment: That is what I thought, but after I read Romans 16 with Phoebe being in the ministry I thought I might have over looked something.

Comment: Phebe is considered to be the messenger that carried the Epistle to the Romans. Women have a very important role in the church, as "succourers" as Paul described Phebe. Feminist movements of today are pushing for equality in the ministry, but they don't realize that men and women cannot replace one another, they *complete* each other. They are not unequal, together they are one flesh, they have different, yet vital roles. Men are the ministers, women are the succourers. Paul commended Phebe of being a succourer of many, including himself.

Comment: I did not think she was a preacher but a deacon. It is not my belief for women to be preachers. Even the bible shows aquilla and priscilla pulling Apollos aside to tell him about Christ.